# Picasso not loading images in ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I wanted to load images from Url into a simple Imageview using Picasso. But unfortunately I am facing some issue. I have included the logs below and the relevant code. I have given Internet permission and using the latest build of Picasso.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTZfC.jpg)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.picassotest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imgView;
    TextView txtView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgView = findViewById(R.id.img_view);
        txtView = findViewById(R.id.txtview);
        Picasso.get().setLoggingEnabled(true);
        Picasso.get().load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500100586562-f75ff6540087?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3589&q=80").into(imgView);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/img_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:text="Hey"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logs

Link: https://pastebin.com/820tP9Jd

Comment: check internet permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true
```

Comment: Solved it. Found out it was the device's fault. For some reason Pixel 2 AVD didn't run the app properly, running on a Pixel XL VD did it. Thank you!